# Make it work: ICU/php-intl mnemonic tag "few" for pluralization formatting

Tags: icu, intl, plural

ICU message formatting doesn't seem to work for me. Here's the example:

```
$n = 22;
$f = MessageFormatter::create('ru', '{n, plural, one{корова} few{коровы} many{коров} other{коров}}');
echo $n.' '.$f->format(['n' => $n])."\n";
```

I get `22 коров` in output, but obviously should get `22 коровы`. Tried on several ubuntu servers.

Language: Russian

php-intl version    1.1.0

ICU version 52.1

Any help will be appriciated, cause I stuck on it.

Answer (score 3):

That's one nasty bug, one that I've spent almost hour figuring out. Well, it turns out in `ICU` 52.1 (probably before, too) we have the following:

```
set34{
    many{
        "v = 0 and i % 10 = 0 or v = 0 and i % 10 = 5..9 or v = 0 and i % 100"
        " = 11..14 @integer 0, 5~19, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, …"
    }
    one{
        "v = 0 and i % 10 = 1 and i % 100 != 11 @integer 1, 21, 31, 41, 51, 6"
        "1, 71, 81, 101, 1001, …"
    }
    other{
        " @integer 2~4, 22~24, 32~34, 42~44, 52~54, 62, 102, 1002, … @decimal"
        " 0.0~1.5, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0, 10000.0, 100000.0, 1000000.0, …"
    }
}
```

Source: http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/tags/release-52-1/source/data/misc/plurals.txt

So, cases of 2-4, 22-24 and so on (`22 коровы`) fall under `other` modifier, so the correct syntax for your case would be `{n, plural, one{корова} few{коровы} many{коров} other{коровы}}`. I left `few` in for compatibility with newer `ICU` versions (which indeed use `few` modifier for this case).